# Pass mean function across a row, and add it as a column to the same dataset you passed it to

Tags: r, apply

I'm sure this has been asked, and there are several ways to do it. BUT, I have searched and still can not find something that works. I tried the 'apply' route but it does not work, and I think it might be b/c the first column is a factor. I would like to calculate the mean of an entire row then add that mean to the end of the row, in a new column with heading 'mean'

Here is what my data frame looks like

```
    stream n          1         2         3         4
1   Brooks 3 0.42707006 1.9353659 1.4333884 1.8566225
2  Siouxon 3 0.90503736 0.2838483 0.2838483 1.0023212
3 Speelyai 3 0.08554021 0.7359903 0.4841935 0.7359903
4   Brooks 4 1.43338843 1.8566225 0.0000000 1.3242210
5  Siouxon 4 0.50574543 0.5057454 0.2838483 0.4756304
6 Speelyai 4 0.32252396 0.4343109 0.6653132 2.2294652
7   Brooks 5 0.88984211 1.8566225 0.7741612 1.3242210
```

However, where the column headings are 1,2,3,4...this goes out to 1000! So really there are 1002 columns, but the first two columns are really vectors, a stream name, then n which is a sample identifier. When I tried the `apply` function it returned this:

```
apply(sim_dat,1,mean)
#  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 
#NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
#27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 
#NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 
#41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 
#NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: @Pascal, thanks for editing my post! looks much better now.

Comment: @Pascal, how did you fix the two blocks of text so they are greyed out and are formatted appropriately.

Comment: When you ask a question, you have a "How to format" help on the right, in a yellow box. And a toolbar on the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowMeans` if you just ignore the first two columns during the calculation. For example

```
sim_dat$mean <- rowMeans(sim_dat[,-(1:2)])
```

This will add a column called `means` with the means of the values for each of the rows excluding the first two columns.

Comment: I would like to keep the first two rows in the dataframe, as they hold key information on where the data came from...

Comment: I'm assuming you meant columns, but this method won't remove them, it just excludes them from the calculation of the means.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what you meant. Not actually remove those first two columns from the data frame, but remove them from the argument you pass.